# Searching for item by property value mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have this collection..

```
const usersSchema = new Schema({
  myUsers : {
   userID : {
    type : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
   },
   isActive : false
  }
})
```

then i want to get right users with `userID` but i dont know how?
i tried this way but it gave me an error

```
const singleUser = req.params.userId;
Users.findOne({
        myUsers.userID: singleUser   
});
```

please tell me how i can search to get right user..

Comment: What's the error thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below snippet

```
const singleUser = req.params.userId;
Users.findOne({"myUsers.userID": singleUser});
```

myUsers.userID needs to be wrapped in quotes

Answer (score 0):

You have the correct syntax. Check this [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IKrqHA_A_JV)

So your problem can the double quotes, because is interpreted as an object, but is only a key into the query object, so you have to do:

```js
Users.findOne({ "myUsers.userID": singleUser });
```

Also check that `singleUser` variable is a valid `ObjectId`.